# Need help formatting a cell value based on a range of other cell values

Tags: google-sheets

I have a range of Cells (B23:B40). I'm trying to set up F12 to work as follows:
if any value in B23:B40 = "Certain Text":
F12 = D19
else:
F12 = D15

I'm not entirely sure how to go about this, I tried daisy chaining =IF()'s but that didn't work because I couldn't default the value to D15. Anyone know how this might be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=if(isna(match("certain text",B23:B40,0)),D15,D19)
```

match is used to determine position of "certain text" in B23:B40 range. If it's not found then match formula returns N/A error.
Isna formula checks whether there is a N/A error.

Try working formula here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f_VE6kQsVxhbu2ZEI96Ij9XaYtCed4n_Oz-NfhoB10M/copy

Comment: Thanks for that, and for explaining what it was doing! That did the trick ^~^

Comment: When you appreciate my answer, please mark the arrow to give me reputation points.

Comment: I clicked the up arrow already, but I don't have enough reputation points myself to mark the arrow >.< It just says that my feedback has been received